# Android :: SQLite, no such column found?

Tags: android-sqlite

Hey all Im a newbie Androidian, and would love some help with this?

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: asd: , while compiling: DELETE FROM labels WHERE name=asd

this is the error am facing, and here's the code:

this is the method in the DBhelper:

```
/**
 * Delete a label table
 * */
public void deleteLabel(String label) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // values.remove(label);

    // Deleting Row
    db.delete(TABLE_LABELS, KEY_NAME + "=" + label, null);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

and here's the main Activity code that invoke the method:

```
// for spinner onItemListener
// and here is what label is

final String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

Button dialogDeletelButton = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        dialogDeletelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // database handler
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                        getApplicationContext());

                // inserting new label into database
                db.deleteLabel(label);

                // Hiding the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputLabel.getWindowToken(), 0);

                // loading spinner without the deleted data
                loadSpinnerData();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You almost certainly need to quote `'asd'` (i.e., the `label` variable in your code). If it's quoted, it's a string to compare against the `name` column.

If it's unquoted, SQL just treats it as another column name.

You could do this in your activity with:

```
db.deleteLabel ("'" + label + "'");
```

but it may be cleaner to change the helper function:

```
db.delete (TABLE_LABELS, KEY_NAME + "='" + label + "'", null);
```

since it looks like you may want to do something with the unquoted label at some point in there (the `ContentValues` stuff which is currently commented out).

Comment: Can you please check this if you can:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178056/android-get-data-from-another-activity

Comment: The ' ' is time killer