# Android: Passing image between two activities

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am trying to send an image back to the Main Activity from another activity after taking then image from the gallery in that activity.The app crashes whilst doing this. How can i solve this? This is my code

Second Activity

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

                        String str = filePath.toString();
                        returnIntent.putExtra("UPDATED_PIC", str);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
```

Main Activity

```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if(data != null) {


                        String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("UPDATED_PIC");
                         //Getting Error here                       
                         filePath = Uri.parse(str);

                        try {
                            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                            // Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                            mNetworkImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Error Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.admin.profilepicture, PID: 4975
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.admin.profilepicture/com.example.admin.profilepicture.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                      at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:475)
                      at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java)
                      at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:437)
                      at com.example.admin.profilepicture.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:61)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: can you please show the error log

Comment: please check your filepath variable it is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write this code on `onActivityResult()` of `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String str = data.getStringExtra("UPDATED_PIC");
    filePath = Uri.parse(str);
}
```

use `data` in place of  `getIntent()` in your `onActivityResult()`

and while calling the SecondActivity you should pass request code also

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178056/get-data-from-another-activity) reference question

Comment: That is what i did.

Comment: you have written `getIntent()` it should be `data`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getIntent()` try using `data.getStringExtra()` in your `onActivityResult()`