# passing Array from Api to to another activity using SharedPreferences and adding to already saved array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences

**INTRO:**
I am trying to pass an array with sub arrays into another activity using sharedpreferences.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**: 
I have an array of data gotten from an api of which I display as a list on a particular activity. 
This is fine as it works.

But I want that on item click, it saves the item data and loads in on another activity. Then on the new activity, I can add new data to that already saved information before closing the activity which then saves the data back to the database on the server.

**REASON:**
I am doing it this way because of slow network connection and smooth page loading. I am trying to use SharedPreferences to save the array on item click, load it up in another activity and then add more data to the already saved array on SharedPreferences.

**CURRENT STATE:**
At the moment, I can only save and get a single variable, not an array.

This is the array:

```
 {  "OutputCode":1,
"OutputMessage":"Success",
"OutputData":[
                {
                    "id":"1",
                    "status":"1",
                    "date_borrowed":"2018-01-16 16:34:01",
                    "date_returned":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "staff_id":"1",
                    "student_id": "1",
                    "log_contents":[{   "id":"8",
                                        "log_id":"1",
                                        "book_id":"1",
                                        "quantity":"3",
                                        "book_info":{   "id":"1",
                                                        "name":"Algebra",
                                                        "author":"John Smith",
                                                        "ISBN":"987-554-3243"}},
                                    {   "id": "5",
                                        "log_id": "1",
                                        "book_id": "1",
                                        "quantity": "2",
                                        "book_info": {  "id": "1",
                                                        "name": "C++",
                                                        "author": "Jane Smith",
                                                        "ISBN": "987-656-3870"}}],
                    "student_details":{"id":"1",
                                    "fname":"John",
                                    "lname":"James",
                                    "username":"username",
                                    "password":"password",
                                    "date_created":"2018-01-15 19:53:41",
                                    "phone":"+15673566"}
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "status": "0",
                    "date_borrowed": "2018-01-13 16:34:01",
                    "date_returned": "2018-01-14 17:10:14",
                    "staff_id": "1",
                    "student_id": "1",
                    "log_contents": [],
                    "student_details": {"id": "2",
                                        "fname": "Mary",
                                        "lname": "Jane",
                                        "username": "username",
                                        "password": "password",
                                        "date_created": "2018-01-15 20:53:41",
                                        "phone": "+14768986"}
                }]}
```

This is the code

```
    access.runCommand("get_all_bookings", keys, values, new AtomAccess.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject output) {
            try {
                String outputCode = output.getString("outputCode");
                String outputMessage = output.getString("outputMessage");

                updtedlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lib_book_list_view);

                if (outputCode.equals("1")) {
                    JSONArray outputData = output.getJSONArray("outputData");
                    for (int i = 0; i < outputData.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = outputData.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject stu = obj.getJSONObject("student_details");
                        Student bookBorrower = new Student(
                                stu.getString("id"),
                                stu.getString("fname"),
                                stu.getString("lname"),
                                stu.getString("username"),
                                stu.getString("password"),
                                stu.getString("date_created"),
                                stu.getString("phone"));
                        JSONArray cont = obj.getJSONArray("log_content");
                        ArrayList<Borrow> contents = new ArrayList<Borrow>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < cont.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject con = cont.getJSONObject(j);
                            JSONObject buk = con.getJSONObject("book_info");
                            contents.add(new Borrow(
                                    con.getString("id"),
                                    con.getString("log_id"),
                                    con.getString("book_id"),
                                    con.getString("quantity"),
                                    new Book(buk.getString("id"),
                                            buk.getString("name"),
                                            buk.getString("author"),
                                            buk.getString("ISBN"))
                            ));

                        }

                        Log log = new Log(
                                obj.getString("id"),
                                obj.getString("status"),
                                obj.getString("date_borrowed"),
                                obj.getString("date_returned"),
                                obj.getString("staff_id"),
                                obj.getString("student_id"),
                                contents,
                                bookBorrower);

                        open_logs.add(log);

                    }
                }

                updtedlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long offset) {

                        Log LogItem = (Log) adapter.getItem(position);

                        Student student = LogItem.getbookBorrower();
                        ArrayList<Borrow> buro = new ArrayList<Borrow>();
                        ArrayList<Book> buk = new ArrayList<Book>();
                        buro = LogItem.getContents();   //Here, am trying to get array of model 'Borrow' and 'Book'
                        Log.v("buro :", ""+buro); // the result here is [com.samuel.booking.entity.Product@e8f6200, com.samuel.booking.entity.Product@aad103]

                        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("fang", ""+student.getFirstName()); // This return the right info
                        editor.putString("lang", ""+buro);  // This yields no result except that in the log above
                        editor.apply();

                        //I was able to get the variable below
                        Intent i =  new Intent(LogsActivity.this, LogInfoActivity.class);
                        // i.putExtra("KEY_log_ID", LogItem.getId());
                        // i.putExtra("KEY_Log_STATUS", LogItem.getStatus());
                        // i.putExtra("KEY_Los_Student_ID", student.getId());
                        // i.putExtra("KEY_Log_Student_FNAME", student.getFirstName())
                        startActivity(i);

                    }

                });

                adapter = new LogsAdapter(LogsActivity.this, open_Logs);
                updtedlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                removeLoadingOverlay();
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
        }
    });
```

I would gladly go with a better way of achieving this. I just want to avoid loading the data from Api all the time.

Comment: save your data in SQLite db.

Comment: " I just want to avoid loading the data from Api all the time." just use SQLite

Comment: I know I can use sQLite, but is it possible with SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Make an `OutputData` object and make it [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), then use `Intent.putExtra()` while starting another `Activity`. It's the right way to pass objects from `Activity` to `Activity`, you should not use `SharedPreferences`. Check out this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/vfbing/passing-objects-between-activities-in-android).

Comment: But can I append data to it on the other activity, then on activity close, pass it back to the former activity

Comment: yes, you should override onActivityResult() and return the new data to it, Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178056/get-data-from-another-activity

Comment: if my answer worked, please accept it as the best answer

Comment: so It worked but not for the array.. it resulted in [com.samuel.booking.entity.Product@e8f6200, com.samuel.booking.entity.Product@aad103]

Comment: am trying to switch to sqlite